# How to solve SSRS 2019 preview "No endpoint" error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

when I try to preview SSRS 2019 report I receive an error message "There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe//localhost/PreviewProcessingService27868/ReportProcessing that could accept the message...". I receive also another error "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 503" after I run report on ReportServer. It started to appear after windows 2016 server restart. Before the restart all reports ran with no problem both on the report server and in preview as well.
Can anybody advise me the solution and clear the problem ?

thanks Petr